# How to read the following path from a servlet?

Tags: servlets, path-parameter

I have a servlet which works on `organizations` address (`@WebServlet("/organizations")`). This way using GET or POST method on address `.../organizations` leads to calling of this servlet. When I need to work with a current organization (for example, 12th), I should call `.../organizations/12`. This way I can write `@WebServlet("/organizations/*")`, but how to read this number (12 in this case)? Or can I replace it with a variable somehow like `@WebServlet("/organizations/{orgNumber}")` (this variant didn't work)?

Comment: Easy to do with Spring's @PathVariable: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-pathvariable

Comment: Can I do it without using Spring?

Comment: Of course.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map it on /organizations/* and extract information from getPathInfo():

```
@WebServlet("/organizations/*")
public class OrganizationsController extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String[] pathInfo = request.getPathInfo().split("/");
        String id = pathInfo[1]; // {id}
        String command = pathInfo[2];
        // ...
       //..
      //.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not give us your code, but you can use the `request` object and string operations to find the part of the request URI you are looking for.

```
@WebServlet("/organizations/*")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // split the complete URI by /
        final var split = request.getRequestURI().split("/");
        // ...
        // or use substrings
        final var partOfPath = request.getRequestURI().substring(20,30);
        // ...
        // or use pathInfo to split only the path following the domain
        final var split = request.getPathInfo().split("/");
        // ...
    }
}
```